# Add Custom Post Type of specific Custom Taxonomy to regularly blog loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I want to add a CPT to be shown in the blog. I figured out that I can use the filter hook `pre_get_post` to get the query object and I can modify it. However just adding another post type to the loop is easily done. But I need to add only specific posts of my CPT which belong to a certain custom taxonomy.

Example:

I have the CPT `shows` and I have a custom taxonomy `series`. Each show can belong to no, one or many series.

-> `show1` belongs to `series1`
-> `show2` belongs to `series2`
-> `show3` belongs to `series1`, `series2`
-> `show4` belongs to no series

I need now to extend the normal blog loop such that `shows` of `series1` and/or `series2` are also listed in the blog.

So in the example either `show1` and `show3` are listed, or `show2` and `show3`, or `show1`,`show2`, and `show3`, but never `show4`.